# Table of contents with page numbers in html

Tags: html, css, printing

I need to **create table of contents** for a big html page, that will be printed.
The only option I've found is CSS3 and it doesn't work in browsers for now (I've tried in FireFox and know that Web Kit doesn't support it either). Here is the [link](http://alistapart.com/article/boom#section7).
Html code:

```
<a class="pageref" href="#figure">see the figure</a>
```

CSS3 code:

```
a.pageref::after { 
  content: " on page " target-counter(attr(href), page) 
}
```

Is there any other way to do this? The way I could use it in FireFox? Because the solution I found is a w3 draft for css3 as I understand and browsers don't support it yet.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I have exactly the same problem and I couldn't use CSS3.

Comment: @Vera rind No, I didn't

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be as simple as this:

```
a.pageref{
    counter-reset: pagecounter;
}

a.pageref:before {
    content: " on page " counter(pagecounter);
    counter-increment: pagecounter;
}
```

[Link here](http://css-tricks.com/numbering-in-style/)

Comment: Your answer works if I had every element on exact page starting from 1, but I have title page and info about element can be 1 page or 3 pages long or other value, so I think I need to make it dynamically @BeatAlex